# Infinite loop when checking roles. VueJS

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, promise, jhipster

There is a navigation bar where elements are displayed depending on the user's role:

```
<b-navbar-toggle
    right
    class="jh-navbar-toggler d-lg-none"
    href="javascript:void(0);"
    data-toggle="collapse"
    target="header-tabs"
    aria-expanded="false"
    aria-label="Toggle navigation">
  <font-awesome-icon icon="bars"/>
</b-navbar-toggle>

<b-collapse is-nav id="header-tabs">
  <b-navbar-nav class="ml-auto">
    <b-nav-item-dropdown
        right
        id="pass-menu"
        v-if="hasAnyAuthority('ROLE_USER') && authenticated"
        :class="{'router-link-active': subIsActive('/pass')}"
        active-class="active"
        class="pointer">
                <span slot="button-content" class="navbar-dropdown-menu">
                    <font-awesome-icon icon="ticket-alt"/>
                    <span>First element</span>
                </span>
    </b-nav-item-dropdown>

    <b-nav-item-dropdown
        right
        id="dictionaries-menu"
        v-if="hasAnyAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN') && authenticated"
        :class="{'router-link-active': subIsActive('/dictionary')}"
        active-class="active"
        class="pointer">
                <span slot="button-content" class="navbar-dropdown-menu">
                    <font-awesome-icon icon="book"/>
                    <span>Second element</span>
                </span>
    </b-nav-item-dropdown>
  </b-navbar-nav>
```

If I set the same roles for both elements, for example `ROLE_USER`, everything works correctly. But when the roles are different for two elements, an infinite loop begins and everything freezes.

Component for checking roles:

```
@Component
export default class JhiNavbar extends Vue {
  @Inject('loginService')
  private loginService: () => LoginService;

  @Inject('accountService') private accountService: () => AccountService;
  public version = VERSION ? 'v' + VERSION : '';
  private currentLanguage = this.$store.getters.currentLanguage;
  private languages: any = this.$store.getters.languages;
  private hasAnyAuthorityValue = false;

  created() {}

  public get authenticated(): boolean {
    return this.$store.getters.authenticated;
  }

  public hasAnyAuthority(authorities: any): boolean {
    this.accountService()
      .hasAnyAuthorityAndCheckAuth(authorities)
      .then(value => {
        this.hasAnyAuthorityValue = value;
      });
    return this.hasAnyAuthorityValue;
  }
}
```

Service for working with user account:

```
export default class AccountService {
  constructor(private store: Store<any>, private router: VueRouter) {
    this.init();
  }

  public init(): void {
    this.retrieveProfiles();
  }

  public retrieveProfiles(): void {
    axios.get('management/info').then(res => {
      if (res.data && res.data.activeProfiles) {
        this.store.commit('setRibbonOnProfiles', res.data['display-ribbon-on-profiles']);
        this.store.commit('setActiveProfiles', res.data['activeProfiles']);
      }
    });
  }

  public retrieveAccount(): Promise<boolean> {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      axios
        .get('api/account')
        .then(response => {
          this.store.commit('authenticate');
          const account = response.data;
          if (account) {
            this.store.commit('authenticated', account);
            if (sessionStorage.getItem('requested-url')) {
              this.router.replace(sessionStorage.getItem('requested-url'));
              sessionStorage.removeItem('requested-url');
            }
          } else {
            this.store.commit('logout');
            this.router.push('/');
            sessionStorage.removeItem('requested-url');
          }
          resolve(true);
        })
        .catch(() => {
          this.store.commit('logout');
          resolve(false);
        });
    });
  }

  public hasAnyAuthorityAndCheckAuth(authorities: any): Promise<boolean> {
    if (typeof authorities === 'string') {
      authorities = [authorities];
    }

    if (!this.authenticated || !this.userAuthorities) {
      const token = localStorage.getItem('jhi-authenticationToken') || sessionStorage.getItem('jhi-authenticationToken');
      if (!this.store.getters.account && !this.store.getters.logon && token) {
        return this.retrieveAccount();
      } else {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
          resolve(false);
        });
      }
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < authorities.length; i++) {
      if (this.userAuthorities.includes(authorities[i])) {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
          resolve(true);
        });
      }
    }

    return new Promise(resolve => {
      resolve(false);
    });
  }

  public get authenticated(): boolean {
    return this.store.getters.authenticated;
  }

  public get userAuthorities(): any {
    return this.store.getters.account.authorities;
  }
}
```

There is solution by @bigless:

```
...
  private hasAdminAuthorityValue = false;
  private hasUserAuthorityValue = false;
...
  public hasAdminAuthority(): boolean {
    this.accountService()
      .hasAnyAuthorityAndCheckAuth('ROLE_ADMIN')
      .then(value => {
        this.hasAdminAuthorityValue = value;
      });
    return this.hasAdminAuthorityValue;
  }

  public hasUserAuthority(): boolean {
    this.accountService()
      .hasAnyAuthorityAndCheckAuth('ROLE_USER')
      .then(value => {
        this.hasUserAuthorityValue = value;
      });
    return this.hasUserAuthorityValue;
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is caused by Vue's reactivity. You use async method in `v-if` statement and it is mostly bad idea. Vue watches all reactive dependencies of this method and if any dependecy changes, it re-evaluates this statement again(which means calling that function again). Thats one part of the story.

Now why this happens only when roles are different. Because you use shared property `hasAnyAuthorityValue` which is reactive dependency of the method mentioned above.

For example: it gets privileges for ROLE_USER, returns `hasAnyAuthorityValue` immediately(sync), but later this value is fetched and updated in promise(async). It can work if async result doesn't change(one role), but when value of `hasAnyAuthorityValue` is toggling between ROLE_USER and ROLE_ADMIN async results, it is trapped in endless loop.

There are many solutions. f.e. save results of both `hasAnyAuthority(any)` as property value of data during create phase or use different property names for each role instead of shared one.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I separate role checking into different methods and it really worked. I added a solution to the question.